# Postfix pipe emails to certain email accounts only

Tags: email, postfix, sendmail

I have configured postfix to run a script when email is received. The script gets tirggered whenever email is received on postfix. However the problem is that it is being triggered on all the email accounts rather than only one account that I added in access file of postfix. 
Here is my configuration: 
**master.cf**

```
myhook unix - n n - - pipe flags=F user=www-data argv=/var/www/public_html/production/hook/hook.php ${sender} ${size} ${recipient}

smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd -o content_filter=myhook:dummy
```

And here is my **main.cf** file:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/access, permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination
```

Here is the content of my access file:

```
robot@domain FILTER myhook:dummy
```

After making above changes I ran:

```
postmap access
postfix reload
```

Still all the emails are being routed to that script rather than only those that are sent to robot@domain

Did I miss something? 
I have followed this tutorial for configurations:

https://thecodingmachine.io/triggering-a-php-script-when-your-postfix-server-receives-a-mail

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE: I've found that there are two approaches to this**

**Approach 1**

Create **transport_maps**:

`/^robot@domain/   myhook:dummy
 /.*/    :`

This forces any mail destined to go to robot@domain to go straight to the hook. Anything else is processed as normal.

Modify **main.cf** to add:

`transport_maps = regexp:/etc/postfix/transport_maps`

Don't forget to run `postmap /etc/postfix/transport_maps` and `postfix reload`

**Approach 2**

*Limitation: mail that is delivered to robot@domain via the local transport will not be filtered*

I got this to work by using a **recipient_access** file like so (note I'm using the regexp syntax):

`/^robot@domain$/    FILTER myhook:dummy
/.*/                 OK`

This will force emails to robot@domain through the filter and allow all other emails to be delivered.

In **main.cf**:

`check_recipient_access =
        regexp:/etc/postfix/recipient_access`

And finally in **master.cf**:

`smtp       inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
    -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=$check_recipient_access`

Do ***not*** specify `-o content_filter=webhook:dummy` because that changes the routing for all messages.

Comment: is it possible use approach 1 and also have a copy of the email saved to the users folder?